# extract json array in jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an array like this:

```
[{"City":"TORONTO ","FSA":"M5T","Province":"ON\r"}]
```

I am getting this data from,

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

I want to put city and province in text field through ajax jquery success.

I tried this in jquery success:

```
data = JQuery.parseJSON(data);
$('txtCity').val(data.City);
```

But, I am not getting actual data.

Comment: It seems like an array so did you try `data[0].City` ??

Answer (score 2):

You have an `array`.

Try this,

```
data = JQuery.parseJSON(data);
$('txtCity').val(data[0].City);
```